# Android frame layout relations in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design a layout but for I can't understand I get error when run in device.

I've gotten error when I use

```
android:layout_above="@+id/frBottom"
```

line. I designed layouts in eclipse and like there is no problem in there.

It's my xml file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/frBottom"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/wvMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#000033" >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove the plus from `android:id="@+id/frBottom"`

Comment: because `@+id/..` is used when you're assigning new id to a view and `@id/..` is used when you're referring to another view.

Comment: @blackbelt You mean from `android:layout_above="@+id/frBottom"`?

Comment: The correct one - `android:layout_above="@id/frBottom"`

Comment: no @Pietu1998, I mean from `android:id="@+id/frBottom"`

Comment: @blackbelt Why? Isn't `@+id` used for adding an ID to a View, and `@id` for referring to one?

Comment: @blackbelt - You are referring the already defined `android:id="@+id/frBottom"` later in some other view with `android:layout_above="@id/frBottom`. So all later referred will be without plus sign.

Comment: Why aren't you using a `LinearLayout`, looks like that's exactly what you need

Comment: @Pietu1998 it is but, layout_about expects and id, and if your provide a not existent id with the plus, it will create the entry in R.id

Comment: @blackbelt But if the ID doesn't exist the whole `layout_above` is pointless, which the error points out if `@id` is used. If `@+id` is used, however, there is nothing to warn about this.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#000033" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/frBottom"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/wvMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Glad to help you and can you please approve ans so it may help others thanks.